# BIRT : Parameter properties and Internationalization

Tags: internationalization, birt

I'm developing multi language reports using BIRT, i've translated almost everything in my report except some Report Parameters property like :

- Prompt Text
- Help Text

I want to translate also Report title property but it seems also impossible to do ...

In the parameter definition i can't find a way to use a string coming from dictionary list , Is there a way to bind this two properties to a dictionary key ?

In the below screenshot the report element that i want to translate :

- Report Parameter Properties : 
  [image: Report Parameter Property Editor]
- Report Title : 
  [image: Report Title Element]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a Parameter
2. Change to "Data Explorer"-View
3. Mark your Parameter
4. Open "Property Editor"-View and select "Localization"
5. Set "Prompt text key" and "Help text key"
6. Create *.properties files, one for every language (e.g. myProp_en.properties, myProp_fr.properties for englisch and france) and fill it with your (dictionary-) keys and the translated text
7. Link your report to your *.properties resource files:

   - select your report file in "Navigator"-View and open it with "Report Editor"
   - select "Layout"-Tab in "Report Editor"
   - Open "Property Editor"-View
   - click in your report to select the properties of your report
   - select in "Property Editor"-View "Resources"
   - set the name of your poperties, in the above example "Resource File" would be named "myProp"

PS: I made screenshots of it but stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post images because of my low reputation :(

Comment: is it possible to use datasource instead of properties resource files?